# Unable to search by number of stars?

Tags: pokemon-go

Looks like the new Pokémon Go update no longer allows to search by 
number of stars your Pokémon is. Can anyone else confirm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bug introduced in the most recent update to the Pokemon Go app broke that search feature. Niantic [acknowledged the bug on Twitter](https://twitter.com/NianticHelp/status/1207017713094160384) earlier today.

Answer (score 5):

This has been fixed in the next minor update (0.163.1 on Android) on the 18th of December 2019. You can now search for your 100% Pokémon again. [Source](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web&s=release-notes-known-issues&f=known-issues) (apart from own experience), emph mine:

> 3) Search Strings 1*, 2*, 3*, and 4* Are Not Working
>
> Issue Description: Search strings 1*, 2*, 3*, and 4*, used to filter Pokémon by appraisal category, are not working.
>
> Issue Status: Fix in recent update (0.163.1)
>
> **Last Updated: December 18th**